# How debug or trace DBus?

Tags: python, c, dbus

I writing Dbus service implementing some protocol. My service sends to client message with unexpected data (library i used has some bugs, that i want to overwrite).

How to inspect, trace client calls? I want to determine what client wants and locate buggy method.

Or how to trace all calls in service? I has much of `logger.debug()` inserted.

Service is python, client is c.

How to specify path or service to monitor in `dbus-monitor` with sender and reciever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbus-monitor "sender=org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Connection.******"`